# Find GPS coordinates of a local point using 2 reference points

Tags: python, algorithm, gps, coordinates, transformation

[image]

Given 2 reference points with known local coordinates and GPS (Decimal Degrees lat,lon) how can you calculate the GPS coordinates of any local point?

Note that I am interested in small areas far from the poles, so the Earth curvature can be omitted for simplicity.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I added a drawing of what I am trying to do. QR1 and QR2 have both local coordinates and GPS. I am looking for points A,B,C and D (essentially any local point).

Comment: Do you have examples?

Comment: OK, So it sounds like you know the "GPS" coordinates\* of two fixed points, and you want to know the coordinates of a third point. But what else do you know about the third point that would be helpful? What do you know about its relationship to the two fixed points? (E.g., do you know its _distance_ from the two fixed points?)

Comment: \*You probably mean [_WGS84_ coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS_84). GPS is a physical system for finding your location on the surface of the Earth.  WGS84 is a mathematical system for identifying locations on the surface of the Earth by means of "latitude" and "longitude" coordinates. Most GPS receivers show the WGS84 coordinates of your location by default, but many of them can be configured to show your location using other systems. (E.g., [_UTM_ coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system))

Comment: In general, two points are not enough. E.g., some coordinate systems are not using geographic north - you have to state these assumptions explicitly, or use more points. Another important question - are local coordinates using some form of geoid, or is it a square grid? - the latter one is particularly important in polar regions

Comment: Thank you all for considering this. I updated the question adding a schematic that I believe will help you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You still have not *explicitly* said what you know about the spatial relationship between the points A, B, C, and D, and the points Q1 and Q2. But the picture you added suggests that point O is the origin of a coordinate system (let's call it "System S") with axes drawn through it. And, it looks as if the System S coordinates of all six points, A, B, C, D, Q1, and Q2, are known.

It also appears that you know the coordinates of Q1 and Q2 in a different coordinate system, which I guess to be WGS84 (a.k.a., "GPS coordinates.")

Is all of that right? If so, then I cannot give you a complete answer, but maybe I can guide your search.

What you probably are asking for is how to find the [*Affine transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) that maps the system S coordinates of any given point to the WGS84 coordinates of the same point.

In practical terms, you're looking for a 3x3 matrix, **A**, such that *w*=**A***s*, where *s* is an "augmented" column vector representing the System S coordinates of some point, and *w* is the corresponding representation of the point's WGS84 coordinates.

Since you already know the coordinates of two points in both systems, what you have to do then is use those coordinates to set up a system of simultaneous equations that you solve to find the matrix, **A**. You then can use that same matrix **A** to transform the System S coordinates of the other points. So long as all of the points in question are not too many miles apart from each other, you should not have to worry about the curvature of the Earth and the fact that WGS84 is not really a Cartesian system.

Unfortunately, here is where I get off this bus. This is the same math that underlies practically all of computer graphics (including the graphics in pretty much all video games.) Sorry to say, it's been a few decades since I did any graphics work, and it's all been pushed out of my head to make room for other projects.

Google is your friend. Anything you can read about computer graphics will be helpful especially if it contains the words, "matrix" and "transform" and either "affine" or "projective."